# Angular - Dynamic Dashbaord depends on user

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 3 type of user: Trainer, sportsmen, fan.

Each 1 do login on same page. But after login i want to show diffrent dashboard depends on user role

Rignt now I try do domething like

```
.state('trainerDashboard', {
               templateUrl: '/App/ControlPanel/views/templates/trainerDashboard.html',
               abstract: true,
           })

state('login', {
                url: '/login',

                templateUrl: '/App/ControlPanel/views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                parent: 'trainerDashboard',
                controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Login_Title',
                    login: true,
                    defaultState: 'users'
                },
                resolve: stateResolve
            })
```

but i dont know how to set different parent here

Any Idea ??

Thank you

Comment: use 1 template and use `ng-if` or `ng-show` according to user roles/permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller what you can define nested states like this

```
.state('dashboard', {
        templateUrl: "/App/ControlPanel/views/templates/dashboard.html"
        controller: ** controllerName ** //your controller name
    })
    .state('dashboard.trainer', {
            url: "/trainer",
            templateUrl: "/App/ControlPanel/views/templates/trainer.html"
        }
        .state('dashboard.sportsman', {
                url: "/sportsman",
                templateUrl: "/App/ControlPanel/views/templates/sportsman.html"
            }
            .state('dashboard.fan', {
                    url: "/fan",
                    templateUrl: "/App/ControlPanel/views/templates/fan.html"
                }
```

And in your controller file you can use $state.go() function provided by Angular UI router to redirect the user to a state on the basis of the user type for example:

```
if(userType == 'trainer'){
    $state.go(dashboard.trainer)
}
else if(userType == 'sportsman'){
    $state.go(dashboard.sportsman)
}
else if(userType == 'fan'){
    $state.go(dashboard.fan)
}
```

And in your dashboard.html file you will have to bind a div with ui-view like this

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

Hope it helps
Cheers